# Fit of a normal distribution to a one-dimensional dataset in R

Tags: r, classification, clustering, normal-distribution

I've got a set of (continuous) values from a measurement, where each object should be either positive or negative, and I know that the values of the "negative" objects should be approximately normally distributed.

I've been using a `k-means`-based algorithm in `R` to cluster the data and thus to classify the objects. Here is a typical example of the clustering result, shown as a density plot:

[image]

As you can see, although the algorithm does distinguish two populations, it includes a part of the positive objects into the negative cluster (the blue one). You can also see that there are some extremely negative outliers, causing the blue curve to be skewed to the right. These outliers are artefacts, resulting from the method the values are measured and calculated, and I'd like to find a cut-off to exclude them in future.

Now, I'd like to fit a normal distribution curve the the negative population and to define a cut-off for those artefacts (outliers) based on this fit as well as to estimate some characteristics of the distribution. I was trying to do this by extracting only those objects that fall into the blue cluster and then fitting a normal distribution on them, but obviously this doesn't work out, mainly due to the bump on the right of the blue population. So I need another classification algorithm that would a priori assume the existence of two Gauss distributions and fit them (in the best case taking into account the possibility of the existence of outliers). However, so far I haven't been able to find an algorithm that would be reliable and fast enough (I've got around 20,000-50,000 objects), although I'm sure there must be a simple way in `R` to do so.

So in summary, I'm looking for a classiciation algorithm implemented in `R` to fit a normal distribution to the "negative" objects of my measurement, ideally taking into account that outliers do exist.

Does anyone has a suggestion how to accomplish this?

Comment: Just a note regarding R: The package `mixtools` ([link](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mixtools/index.html)) is what you need to fit a GMM as noted by Pat below. The function `normalmixEM` implements the EM algorithm for the mixture of univariate normal. Use the option `k` to specify the number of components (`k=2` for a two component and `k=3` for a three component mixture).

Comment: @COOLSerdash Thanks for the hint! I've just tried it out, and it really seems to do what I wanted!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like a two component gaussian mixture model would be exactly what you're looking for.

I don't tend to use R, but GMMs are so commonly used I can't imagine it they're not implemented somewhere. If you really can't find them anywhere then they're not too hard to implement yourself. Wikipedia has the exact expectation maximisation update steps (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_model#Expectation_maximization_.28EM.29). Note that it's very similar to the kmeans update steps, so should run in about the same time.

Dealing with outliers is a little more fiddly. One option might be to include a third gaussian in your mixture model, and ensure it has a low mixture weight and a high variance (by setting an appropriate prior, or just estimating and fixing the values). Hopefully that'll sweep up the few outliers there are while letting the other components model the data you're interested in.